# issues with a slider - investigations with firebug

Tags: css, html

issues with a slider on the page: http://www.ex-libri.org

see the amazon-link-slider (carousel) within a posting on the page:

```
a.jcarousel-control-next (button) 
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">‹</a>
```

ever time i press a net button the site does work somewhat nasty – the carousel does *not* work. Well i have no glue why this is so?

I will try to investigate –

look forward to any and all help.

**update:** thanks to this great answer: it helps alot! it is all about the plugin – the amazon-link plugin with the carousel on two sites: see the first one where all goes well: here we have the following

http://www.literaturen.org/wp-content/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?ver=1.0

here the link leads to some *content* there a file is represented…

and now – compare to the second site;

see the link accordingly;

/wp-content/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?ver=1.0

note: this is empty – so we have some interesting findings….

i think that there the file is **missing**

i will do some further investigations and come back and report all findings,

Answer (score 0):

The .js file for the carousel is not loading, I get a 404 instead:

```
GET http://www.ex-libri.org/wp-content/plugins/jquery.jcarousel.min.js?ver=1.0 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 98ms]
```

It looks like either there is a plugin's subfolder missing in the path or the path of plugins folder has been used instead of the theme path.

Comment: ....many thanks - see the edited posting above...i  guess that you have  found out very important things..!!  They lead me to further einvestigations